# Problema con los headers al hacer una consulta en mongoDB con NODEJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Tengo un problema al intentar hacer una consulta en mongo, el problema es el siguiente:

Intento crear un nuevo usuario, y si este ya existe, devolver un json con un status de error, la inserccion a la bd lo hacer correctamente, el problema esta cuando inserto un usuario ya registrado, que sale el siguiente error en la consola: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
function newUser(req, res) {
    var params = req.body;
    var user = new User();

    if (params.name && params.surname && params.nick && params.email && params.password) {
        user.name = params.name;
        user.surname = params.surname;
        user.nick = params.nick;
        user.email = params.email;
        user.role = 'ROLE_USER';
        user.image = null;

        User.find({
            $or: [
                { email: user.email.toLowerCase() },
                { nick: user.nick.toLowerCase() }
            ]
        }).exec((err, users) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error en la peticion' });

            if (users && users.length >= 1) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'El usuario ya existe' });
            }
        });

        //Cifra la contraseña y guarda los datos en la bd
        bcrypt.hash(params.password, null, null, (err, hash) => {
            user.password = hash;
            user.save((err, usuarioGuardado) => {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al guardar el usuario' });

                if (usuarioGuardado) {
                    res.status(200).send({ user: usuarioGuardado });
                } else {
                    res.status(404).send({ message: 'No se ha registrado el usuario' });
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: "Rellena todos los campos necesarios!!"
        });
    }
}
```

El error solo aparece cuando entra en el if de que el usuario existe, cuando no existe el usuario registrado inserta los datos sin problema.
He intentado mil cosas y no logro solucionarlo, gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Porqué hacer una validación así? Si tu modelo lo configuras para que tanto el campo `email` como el campo `nick` sean de tipo [`unique`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique), entonces solo basta con realizar un sólo paso: `save()`. Si al salvar el documento obtienes un error, basta con determinar si el mismo es sobre la condición de algunos de los campos. Esto evita la doble consulta sobre tu BD. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, si aceptas mi consejo, no hagas el `hash` del `password` como un proceso del controlador o de la función `middleware`. Mi sugerencia es delegar esa tarea al `Schema` mediante un método [`pre`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre). La idea es encapsular lo máximo posible tu modelo de datos. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que el método `exec` es asíncrono, es decir, le pasas un callback para que se ejecuta cuando haya ejecutado la query. Y al ser asíncrono el callback de `bcrypt.hash` se ejecuta antes y se envia una respuesta, por lo cual cuando mongo acaba de ejecutar la query y ejecuta el callback

```
exec((err, users) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error en la peticion' });

    if (users && users.length >= 1) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'El usuario ya existe' });
    }
})
```

el servidor ya ha devuelto una respuesta desde el callback de `bcrypt` y por ese te sale ese error.

```
(err, hash) => {
    user.password = hash;
    user.save((err, usuarioGuardado) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al guardar el usuario' });

        if (usuarioGuardado) {
            res.status(200).send({ user: usuarioGuardado });
        } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'No se ha registrado el usuario' });
        }
    });
}
```

Para arreglar, dicho error con añadir el código de hashear la contraseña en el callback de `exec` sería suficiente. El flujo del programa será el correcto.

```
function newUser(req, res) {
    var params = req.body;
    var user = new User();

    if (params.name && params.surname && params.nick && params.email && params.password) {
        user.name = params.name;
        user.surname = params.surname;
        user.nick = params.nick;
        user.email = params.email;
        user.role = 'ROLE_USER';
        user.image = null;

        User.find({
            $or: [
                { email: user.email.toLowerCase() },
                { nick: user.nick.toLowerCase() }
            ]
        }).exec((err, users) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error en la peticion' });

            if (users && users.length >= 1) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'El usuario ya existe' });
            }

            //Cifra la contraseña y guarda los datos en la bd
            bcrypt.hash(params.password, null, null, (err, hash) => {
                user.password = hash;
                user.save((err, usuarioGuardado) => {
                    if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al guardar el usuario' });

                    if (usuarioGuardado) {
                       return res.status(200).send({ user: usuarioGuardado });
                    } else {
                        return res.status(404).send({ message: 'No se ha registrado el usuario' });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: "Rellena todos los campos necesarios!!"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!, me sirvió para solucionar el problema!