# validar cuenta de usuario a través de un correo y redireccionar después de activar la cuenta

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, validación, tokens

tengo un problema que no he podido resolver, estoy un poco enredado y quisiera obtener alguna ayuda.

Estoy haciendo el registro de usuario de un proyecto personal pero quiero hacerlo de una forma bonita, funcional y lo más correcta que se pueda para un novato como yo. ya tengo el registro en la BD y luego procedo a enviar un correo de confirmación de cuenta con un link, cabe destacar que también estoy usando tokens para el acceso a recuros del servidor. El link lo creo con un hash + el id del usuario en la BD; el enlace termina viéndose así:

`http://localhost:3000/ActivateAccount/?hash=$2b$10$uKG9PkUYjt.xyUXCEOhTCepo58g2deN5FYROAjsYa/KjEjNK5eGDS&id=34`

Luego estoy intentando responder a ese link de la siguiente forma en el servidor:

```js
router.get('/ActivateAccount', (req, res) => {
 // mostrar una página con un mensaje que indique que se está validando su cuenta
 // realizar operaciones en la bd para activar la cuenta del usuario
 // redireccionar a la página de inicio de ese usuaio ( como si se fuese logueado )

})
```

Acá es dónde tengo muchas complicaciones y estoy muy confundido, no se como programar la primera y la última línea comentadas en el código anterior. Lo que quisiera lograr es que cuándo el usuario haga click en el enlace, se muestre una página donde tal vez pudiera a parecer un loading spinner mientras en paralelo se están ejecutando las operaciones en la Base de datos para activar la cuenta y, que al finalizar dichas operaciones y esté validada la cta,  se muestre un alert diciendo que la cuenta se ha validado y con un boton de "aceptar", y que el usuario al hacer click allí se redirija a la pagina de bienvenida para ese usuario.

Algo así como hace Facebook, cuándo ya se ha validado la cuenta, muestra una pequeña ventana diciendo que todo esta listo, y al hacer click en aceptar automáticamente te redirige a tu página de inicio, así como aparece en la siguiente imágen.

[image: facebook]

¿Cuáles son mis mayores problemas?

1) como haría para mostrar una página desde el servidor (la página que quiero que cargue mientras se realizan las operaciones en la BD) ? leí sobre servir archivos estáticos pero no estoy muy claro, entiendo que se puede renderizar una página en express con render pero ya lo probé, y al hacer eso como que se envía la respuesta al cliente de una vez y entonces las sentencias luego del render no se ejecutan.

2) la página que envío en el link, obviamente debe ser con el puerto del servidor, correcto? estoy trabajando con angular (puerto 4200) y node.js con Express (puerto 3000). para poder recibir los parámetros y procesarlos en el servidor, el link debe ser con el puerto del servidor, como lo mostré anteriormente o estoy equivocado?

3) he leído que los parámetros para validar la cuenta no debería ir en el link (por GET ) para protegerlos, pero he visto que así los envían mayormente los foros y páginas como Facebook.

Este es un ejemplo del link enviado por Facebook:

`facebook.com/confirmemail.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&rd&__req=n`

Este es un ejemplo del link enviado por un foro:

`https://www.foromecanicos.com/foro/account-confirmation/julian21931500.163342/email?c=1mGlZh9aoHEKoG1L`

Sinceramente he buscado opciones, pero no he encontrado algo que me ayuda, espero alguien acá puede orientarme un poco, gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta hacer una página renderizada en el server, desde angular lo puedes hacer perfectamente.

Cuando envías la url en el correo de activación manda la url de angular a la ruta que cargue el componente de activar cuenta.

```
http://localhost:4200/ActivateAccount/?hash=$2b$10$uKG9PkUYjt.xyUXCEOhTCepo58g2deN5FYROAjsYa/KjEjNK5eGDS&id=34
```

En la parte servidor, puedes crear un endpoint que sea `/activar-cuenta`

```
router.post('/activar-cuenta', (req, res) => {
  // leer datos del req.body
  // hacer el get del usuario por id
  // validar el token
  // y confirmar la cuenta
  // todos estos pasos dependen de la implementación que tengas en el backend
  // devolver una respuesta en función de la validación 
});
```

En la parte de angular puedes crear una ruta que sea la de activar cuenta, por ejemplo.
En el archivo de las rutas

```
// puedes poner un guard que valide que esta ruta se active solo si no está logueado el usuario
{
    path: 'ActivateAccount',
    component: ActivarCuenta
}
```

En tu componente `ActivarCuenta`

```
// es un pseudocodigo
constructor(private router: Router) {}
loading = true;
ngOnInit() {
   // leer los query params de la url
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.validateAccount(hash, id);
    });
}

validateAccount(hash, id) {
    // hacer una peticion post al endpoint /activar-cuenta con el user id y hash
    // esperar la repuesta
    // si todo va ok quitar loading 
    //mostrar un modal/alert dando el mensaje de activación
    // redirigir al login
}
```

La parte de hacer login en activar cuenta no te la recomiendo porque no tienes la contraseña (se que puedes hacer un get del usuario y la tienes pero no es muy recomendable) mejor luego de activar la cuenta redirigir a la pagina de login en angular.

Comment: Ante todo gracias por responder, ahora siento que estoy un poco más claro. Entiendo lo que menciones del login, pero como hace Facebook en ese caso? Tendrás idea? Yo tengo una tabla llamada "cuenta" con 3 col (id que hace ref a la tabla user, hash y activa), en mi pregunta mencioné que estoy haciendo uso de tokens y obviamente no se puede entrar al home sin un token, pero lo q se me había ocurrido era: al validar la cuenta, establecer la columna activa en true, dejar el hash, y entonces redireccionae al home, y en el Middleware que tengo al entrar al home verificar, si la col activa esta

Comment: En "true" y el hash está todavía en la tabla cuenta (esto me dice que el usuario se acabó de registrar) entonces autorizó el acceso y muestro el home y no solicito un token (por qué es la primera vez que ingresa como user nuevo) y elimino el hash de la tabla cuenta, si la col hash está vacia, quiere decir que la cuenta ya fue validada en algún momento y entonces se solicita el token. Crees que esté bien así? Todo esto con el fin de poder redireccionar al home una vez que se haya validado la cuenta y el user haga click en el botón aceptar como en Facebook. Tengo días en esto.

Comment: a que te refieres como lo hace facebook? la activación de la cuenta? Sinceramente no se al respecto, depende mucho del caso de uso. Me parece bien lo que comentas tener una tabla con active, hash y userid. Cuando te llamen al endpoint de `activar-cuenta` luego de validar el `hash` puedes poner `active=true` y el hash borrarlo porque una vez validada la cuenta no veo mucho sentido tenerlo. Pero si quieres tenerlo para temas de historial, pues como tu veas.

Comment: Y esta bien de tener un middleware(en nodejs) que valide si el usuario está activo  sino es así puedes devolver un header o un json con `active=false` y con los interceptores de angular interceptar esa respuesta y mostrar una alert de reenviar correo de confirmación o activa tu cuenta.

Comment: Tambien cuando el user hace login puedes devolver que no esta activo y no dejar avanzar a la home. Para ea generación token puedes usar el paquete de node `crypto`.

Comment: Cuando el usuario se registra en tu pagina luego de hacer el registro en nodejs manda el correo el de activación al usuario.

Comment: Con lo de Facebook me refiero a que cuando el user haga click en el botón aceptar redirecciona automáticamente al home (sin necesidad de tener q obligar al user a loguearse), eso es lo que quisiera hacer para mejorar un poco la UX, así sería algo menos que el user haga. Creo que con eso que te comenté (haciendo uso de la tabla cuenta), podría lograr eso, no? Al parecer no voy tan mal ?

Comment: Se puede hacer, pero creo que Facebook tiene ciertas pagina que son server side rendered. Pero la arquitectura de tu app es distinta, es SPA(single page application) que se comunica a través de una api con el backend. Pero con JWT tokens tambien se puede hacer luego de activar la cuenta puedes generar el token que generas en el login y en angular pues setear dicho token en session storage o localstorage eso como tu veas. y hacer la redirección a la home

Comment: Si, también había pensado en generar el token al momento de que el usuario se registrar y enviarlo de una vez (ahí creo q no necesitaría usar el hash de la tabla cuenta), pero alguien me dijo q no era necesario crear el token (cuándo yo no había siquiera pensado en implementar la verificación de la cuenta por correo) y entonces me olvidó de hacerlo así, es que he buscado tanta info que aveces avanzó un paso y luego veo que era mejor de otra forma y termino retrocediendo 2 pasos. Con esta info que me diste y haciéndolo como te comento creo que me va a funcionar.

Comment: mirate esto https://codemoto.io/coding/nodejs/email-verification-node-express-mongodb.

Comment: Voy a leerlo y voy a comenzar con la implementación de lo que comentaste para probar. En caso de que me surja una nueva duda, estarás activo por acá?

Comment: un rato si sino ya mañana

Comment: Hola amigo, estoy todavía tratando de implementar esto, y tengo un pequeño inconveniente que no he podido resolver. en el endpoint, hago las operaciones respectivas en la BD y todo bien, luego de eso èstoy haciendo un ```redirect( 'http://www.google.com')``` y simplemente no muestra nada el navegador, en el inspector de red me marca la solicitud en rojo y en la pestaña de headers dice: ```provisional headers are shown```. Antes había hecho un redirect solo para probar y me hacía la redirección sin problemas, no se si tenga que ver con que debo de devolver una respuesta al front, no entiendo.

Comment: no puedes hacer `redirect` desde node lo tienes que hacer desde angular porque tu aplicación no server side rendered. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358481/problema-con-los-headers-al-hacer-una-consulta-en-mongodb-con-nodejs/358492#358492

Comment: tendrás un tiempo para una consulta por chat para no extender los comentarios acá?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108764/discussion-between-hawks-and-julianprog).